# IntegrityError at /send/ NOT NULL constraint failed: user_transactions.user_id

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

`enter code here`models

class Transactions(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,related_name='accounts',on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True) recipient_account_type = models.CharField(max_length=230) recipient_name = models.CharField(max_length=100) recipient_acount_number = models.PositiveIntegerField() recipient_routing_number = models.PositiveIntegerField() recipient_bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200) recipient_swift_code = models.CharField(max_length=100) recipient_sending_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2) transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) transaction_ID =models.IntegerField(default=ID) description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

forms

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['recipient_account_type','recipient_name','recipient_acount_number',
            'recipient_routing_number','recipient_bank_name','recipient_swift_code','recipient_sending_amount','description',]
        Widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':'autofocus','size':'40', 'font-size':'xx-large'})
```

views

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def send(request):
    posts =Transactions.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form =  TransactionForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/success/')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            # messages.error(request, 'Failed, Resend')
    context = {'form':form,'posts':posts}
    return render(request, 'index_user/send-money.html', context)

**template**
{% extends 'about/user-base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block content %}
  
  <!-- Content
  ============================================= -->
  <div id="content" class="py-4">
    <div class="container"> 
      
  
      <div class="row mt-4 mb-5">
        <div class="col-lg-11 mx-auto">
          <div class="row widget-steps">
            <div class="col-12 step active">
              <div class="step-name">Details</div>
            
              <a href="#" class="step-dot"></a> </div>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2 class="fw-400 text-center mt-3">Send Money</h2>
      <p class="lead text-center mb-4">Send your money at anytime, anywhere in the world.</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-18 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 mx-auto bg-primary">
          <div class="bg-white shadow-sm rounded p-3 pt-sm-4 pb-sm-5 px-sm-5 mb-4">
            <hr class="mx-n3 mx-sm-n5 mb-4">
            <div class="bg-white shadow-sm rounded p- pt-sm-5 pb-sm-5 px-sm-5 mb-4 bg-secondary">
              <div class="text-center bg-primary p-4 rounded mb-4">
                <h3 class="text-10 text-white fw-400">${{user.account_balance|intcomma}}</h3>
                <p class="text-white">Available Balance</p>
                {% comment %} <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm shadow-none text-uppercase rounded-pill text-1">Withdraw Full Amount</a> </div> {% endcomment %}
            <!-- Send Money Form
            ============================ -->
            <p style="color: red; font-size:large">
            {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            {{message}}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            </p>
            
            <center style="background-color: #007bff;">
            <form id="form-send-money" method="POST" action="" class="bg-success" >
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="mb-3 pb-sm-5 px-sm-5">
                {% comment %} <label for="withdrawto" class="form-label">Withdraw From</label> {% endcomment %}
                <br>
                {% comment %} <select id="withdrawto" class="form-select px-sm-4 pb-sm-1" name="">
                  <option value="">FNMB Bank - {{user.account_number}}</option>
                </select> {% endcomment %}
              </div>
              <div id="id_long_desk" class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-9">
                <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Full Name</label>
                <br>
              {{form.recipient_name}}
              </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Account Number</label>
              <br>
              {{form.recipient_acount_number}}
            </div>
              <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
                <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Bank Name</label>
                <br>
              {{form.recipient_bank_name}}
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
                <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Routing Number</label>
                <br>
                  {{form.recipient_routing_number}}
              </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Swift Code</label>
              <br>
              {{form.recipient_swift_code}}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Account Type</label>
              <br>
              {{form.recipient_account_type}}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Recipient Sending Amount</label>
              <br>
              {{form.recipient_sending_amount}}
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Description</label>
              <br>
              {{form.description}}
            </div>
            {% comment %} <div class="mb-3 px-sm-4 pb-sm-1">
              <label for="emailID" class="form-label">Fees</label>
              <br>
              $ {{form.fees}}
            </div> {% endcomment %}
              <!-- <p>Transfer Fees <span class="float-end"> 12.21 USD</span></p> -->
              <hr>
              <div class="d-grid"><button class="submit btn btn bg-white">Send</button></div>
              <hr>
            </form>
          </center>
            <!-- Send Money Form end --> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Content end --> 
  
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your form is valid with something like the following?

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
else:
    # errror handling? debug with form.errors...
```

If your code does look like above, please add more info (like the form handling method as a whole)

Comment: I did that, it shows the form is invalid, it even redirect me to the url after the save function is called but there’s nothing in database

Comment: If it is invalid, then it will not be created in the databsae. What can you see with `print(form.errors)`?

Comment: Sorry, i mean the form is valid, it goes to the url after the save() function is called but the database is empty

Comment: OK, then we probably need further info. Please edit your original post and let us know how `form` is created, and how its corresponding model looks like

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqxhc.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OULrb.jpg

Comment: try `form.save()` instead of `form.save`

Comment: form.save() shows error

Comment: IntegrityError at /send/
NOT NULL constraint failed: user_transactions.total

Comment: You can add `null=True` to the`total` field of `Transactions` model

Comment: still same error, if i remove the parenthesis from the from the form.save() function it works but don't save in the database and it won't through any error, i cannot post any form from my project to data base but i can post from database to template

Comment: Please don't remove the parens otherwise nothing will be written into the database.

Have you migrated after the null constraint change?

Comment: Yes, i migrated

Comment: can you print the value of the field `total` in `form`? And please also post your `TransactionForm` definition

Comment: I have added the form picture and a link to the project

Comment: I think the same error you mentioned should be referring to another field, if the `total` field has already been changed to nullable. You need to add all non-nullable fields to the form fields, including foreign keys like `user`.

Comment: All fields added to form, I’m still having the same error

Comment: Please try the following: print all the fields and see which one has an empty value. Then check it against your model, then you should find out where goes wrong

Comment: def send(request):
    posts =Transactions.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    form =  TransactionForm()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = TransactionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/success/')
        else:
            print(form)

Comment: i tried printing form but its not showing

Comment: not inside `else`, print it in `if` since your form is valid

Comment: When i remove the foreignkey, it save’s fine

Comment: <bound method Log.error of <distutils.log.Log object at 0x0000027E0B5179D0>>

Comment: I’m new to django, How can i pass in user? It seems it’s my foreignkey is none

Comment: That depends on how you want your user to be added. Via html form? Then you need to expose it back to your model form. You can find details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/